# Alignment of equation number with the end of the line

Tags: equations

I' trying to reproduce this equation array from an IEEE paper

[image]

you can see that the equation numbers are aligned at the end of the line same as the above statement.

my code:

```
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
%
I(\lambda)\;\;\; &= &\;\;\;\int_{}^{}\int_{D}^{} g(x,y) e^{i \lambda h (x,y)}dx\,dy.\\
\prod_{j\geq0}^{}\bigg(\sum_{k\geq0}^{}a_{jk} z^k\bigg)\;\;\;\; &=&\;\;\;\;\sum_{n\geq0}^{}z^n \Bigg(\sum_{\substack{k_0,k_1,...\geq0\\k_0+k_+...=n}}^{}a_{0k_0}a_{1k_1} \, . \, . \, . \,\Bigg).\IEEEeqnarraynumspace\\
%
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
```

It produces:

[image]

you can see that the equation numbers shifted to the left and aren't aligned with the above statement.

[image]

If I add spaces more, the numbers shift and start to interleave with the statement of the second column in the paper.

So, I want to know how to force the equation numbers to be aligned at the end of the line.

Any help is appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: use the `align` environment from amsmath and everything will be fine.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the second equation is too wide for the column. However, you just need to fix the wrong things inside it:

1. the `\;` commands around `=` should be removed
2. use `\iint` instead of `\int\int`
3. `\Bigg` should be `\biggl` and `\biggr`

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum,xcolor} % just for the example

\begin{document}

%% the line below is a trick to show the margin
\hspace*{\fill}\rlap{\color{red}\smash{\vrule depth 8cm width 0.2pt}}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
I(\lambda) &=& \iint_{D} g(x,y) e^{i \lambda h (x,y)}dx\,dy.\\
\prod_{j\geq0}\biggl(\,\sum_{k\geq0}^{}a_{jk} z^k\biggr) &=&
  \sum_{n\geq0} z^n
    \biggl(
    \sum_{\substack{k_0,k_1,\dotsc\geq0\\k_0+k_1+\dotsb=n}}a_{0k_0}a_{1k_1} \dotsm
    \biggr).
  \IEEEeqnarraynumspace
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]